# AC Charger Information paragraph has no info about serial number

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

Just noticed that there is no any info about the charger serial number in **System Information > Power > AC Charger Information**. Is it okay?

```
AC Charger Information:
  Connected:  Yes
  ID:         0x0000
  Wattage(W): 94
  Family:     0xe000400a
  Charging:   Yes
```

I found a serial number on the charger but for some reason, my Mac doesn't identify it.
I'm using a MacBook Pro 2018 15-inch (Model A1990) and an 87 W Type-C Adapter. Both adapter and cable have serial numbers. First three letters of cable serial number: `DLC`

Comment: √\AC Charger Information:

  Connected: Yes
  ID: 0x0aa1
  Wattage (W): 85
  Family: 0x0085
  Serial Number: 0x009e266a
  Charging: No

Comment: Probably not talking to the SMC, try SMC reset